# How can I write statement in more intelligent and shorter way? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, data-structures

I'm checking the `count`. If key `B` does not have `count`, then show `777`, otherwise, show the actual `count`. In this case, there is no `count` so I should show `777`.

**Is there any way to write this `if else` statement in a more intelligent and shorter way?**

And not to mention `if len(list) ==0:` I don't want that.

The code:

```
results = [{'A': [{'_id': {}, 'count': 256}], 'B': []}]

if not results[0]['B']:
    updated_events = 777
else:
    updated_events = results[0]['B'][0]['count']
    
print(updated_events)
```

Comment: With *not to mention `if len(list) ==0:`* you mean not to mention this check `if not results[0]['B']` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct a dictionary from `'B'` contents and call `dict.get` method with default value `777`:

```
updated_events = dict(*results[0]['B']).get('count', 777)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
results = [{'A': [{'_id': {}, 'count': 256}], 'B': []}]

updated_events = results[0]['B'][0].get('count') if results[0]['B'] else 777
            
print(updated_events)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    updated_events = results[0]['B'][0]['count']
except LookupError:
    updated_events = 777
```

The `LookupError` is the parent class of both `KeyError` and `IndexError`.